# Cannot build kaa sandbox app endpoint ownership due to android license issue

Tags: android, sandbox, kaa

I am testing the Endpoint Ownership app in the kaa sandbox. when downloading the app for android from

[image]

I got the following errors:

verifiers_demo/appcompat_v7/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png
verifiers_demo/appcompat_v7/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
verifiers_demo/appcompat_v7/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha.png
verifiers_demo/social-networks-sdks.zip
Building binary file...
File /home/kaa/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Build-Tools 25, Android SDK Platform 25].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.68 secs
Unexpected error occurred: Process returned bad exit value: 1
Unexpected service error occurred: Process returned bad exit value: 1
Failed!

I tried all kinds of approaches google could find, such as

android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-25.0.1,android-25,extra-android-m2repository

, and also restarted the kaa sandbox. But none has helped. Keep getting the same build error.

I am using the sandbox on the AWS AMI of version v0.10.0.

Please help solve this android license issue (not a android developer myself).

Thanks a lot.

James

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug of the Sandbox build for AWS. We created an issue for this in the Kaa issue tracker. You can track its status by the next link: [APP-603](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/APP-603).